# Aspnetcore Web API suppress properties if Default value

Tags: .net-core

I want to have small JSON files for my API.

For this I asked myself if these values could be suppressed in default JSON handling in aspnetcore Web API 3.1:

```
"allowNewsletter": false, // bool
"dataPrivacyEmail": "" // or if not string.Empty possible, at least 'null'
"dataPrivacyEmail": null, // string
"articleSortType": 0, // int
```

Already searched for settings in `JsonOptions` (`Startup.cs` in `ConfigureServices`):

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = true;
    });
```

Is there any way to suppress the properties for `int`, `bool` or `string`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, in .net core there is no support for this, but they are looking to implement this for .net 5

There is already an issue open on github
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/779